# Return Category From Another Table by Comparing The Value with Min and Max

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I am trying to get a column which specify the points by comparing the value from original table to min and max value from another table. I have a main table, which consists of few columns of values and the respective point column to be inserted. Here is the example:

```
Main table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User   | Department |  BU  |  Revenue | Revenuepoint | Profit |  Profitpoint |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A      | 1000000    | 101  |  400     |              | 200    |              |
| B      | 1000001    | 101  |  300     |              | 100    |              |
| C      | 1000000    | 102  |  350     |              | 150    |              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Point table
---------------------------------------------------------
| Category| Department |  BU  |  From  | To    | Point  |
---------------------------------------------------------
| Revenue | 1000000    | 101  |  0     | 200   | 1      |
| Revenue | 1000000    | 101  |  201   | 400   | 2      |
| Revenue | 1000000    | 102  |  0     | 300   | 1      |
| Revenue | 1000000    | 102  |  301   | 400   | 2      |
| Revenue | 1000001    | 101  |  0     | 200   | 1      |
| Revenue | 1000001    | 101  |  201   | 400   | 2      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 101  |  0     | 100   | 1      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 101  |  101   | 300   | 2      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 102  |  0     | 50    | 1      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 102  |  51    | 200   | 2      |
| Profit  | 1000001    | 101  |  0     | 50    | 1      |
| Profit  | 1000001    | 101  |  51    | 200   | 2      |
---------------------------------------------------------


Expected table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User   | Department |  BU  |  Revenue | Revenuepoint | Profit |  Profitpoint |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A      | 1000000    | 101  |  400     |       2      | 200    |       2      |
| B      | 1000001    | 101  |  300     |       2      | 40     |       1      |
| C      | 1000000    | 102  |  350     |       2      | 150    |       2      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried a few ways that i found in here, but most not as complex as mine so i have no idea how to move from here.

This is the code that i tried

```
SELECT a.User, a.Department, a.BU, a.Revenue, b.Point as Revenuepoint
FROM Sales a
JOIN Point b ON a.Revenue BETWEEN b.fromvalue and b.tovalue
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like both of your tables not joined correctly and condition should come after WHERE statement, there is no WHERE in your query. Try below code.

```
`SELECT a.User,a.Department, a.BU, a.Revenue, b.Point as Revenuepoint
FROM Sales a
INNER JOIN Point b ON a.Department = b.Department
WHERE a.Revenue BETWEEN b.fromvalue AND b.tovalue`
```

Comment: I see. now i got it. but what about the profit column? i could do the union but actually theres like 50 more columns as revenue and profit so i do not intend to do union

Answer (score 0):

In below way you can add any column to the select (Column should be in a or b in your scenario)

```
`SELECT a.User,a.Department, a.BU, a.Revenue, b.Point as Revenuepoint,a.Profit
FROM Sales a
INNER JOIN Point b ON a.Department = b.Department
WHERE a.Revenue BETWEEN b.fromvalue AND b.tovalue`
```

Since you're only looking for a.Revenue between b.fromvalue and b.tovalue`, there is no need to use union, Simple select query with the profit column will solve your problem.

Comment: yes but the profit also has to show its points in profitpoint column

Comment: Above code have the profit column too. run the query and check again.

Comment: need both Profit column and Profitpoint column

Comment: Simply add the needed column to the select query from its respective table.

Comment: and where do i compare the profit? should it be OR after WHERE a.Revenue BETWEEN b.fromvalue AND b.tovalue ?

Comment: `SELECT a.User,a.Department, a.BU, a.Revenue, b.Point as Revenuepoint,a.Profit,b.point AS profitpoint
FROM Sales a
INNER JOIN Point b ON a.Department = b.Department
WHERE a.Revenue BETWEEN b.fromvalue AND b.tovalue`


No need to compare anywhere. Above query will populate the profitpoint column as well. I reccomend you to go through this for better understanding about SQL - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: i did that and the profitpoint shows the result SAME as revenuepoint. i know this because of the usage WHERE there only caters a.Revenue. You notice in my Point table there got a column called Category right?